# Spring - two listeners inside xml file

Tags: spring, listener, web.xml

I have been looking for answer but I couldn't find anything that would resolve my problem, I have web.xml file where I had one listener and it was okay

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

However when I want to add additional to check sessions

```
<listener>
 <listener-class>org.springframework.security.ui.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Application does not even load, there are no errors or anything, any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Your syntax is fine, place your filters before <servlet> and everything should work. I'd look for problems somewhere elso.

Comment: The point is that the only one thing I'm changing is adding that listener, anyways thats

Comment: ok, so maybe try adding another listener, instead of HttpSesstionEventPublisher you can try org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener and check if it works

Comment: It works fine with org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener seems that something is wrong with that httpSessionEventPublisher, changed it back to httpSessionEventPublisher but different one, from spring official site and it is working now, weird but well, thank you very much for help

Comment: maybe you don't have it available on your classpath and ClassNotFoundException is hidden somewhere because of wrong logging configuration

Comment: @PiotrekDe Doesn't servlet 3.0 remove the need for the ordering in web.xml?

Comment: Depending on which version of Spring Security you are using it isn't in the ui package but the web package. `org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher`, it has been so since the 3.0 release of Spring Security earlier versions had it in the ui package.

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax is:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.security.ui.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
  <!-- (...) -->
</servlet>
```

If you have defined it in this way, everything should work fine.